# Android AsyncHttpClient: how to POST multipart form data?

Tags: android, androidhttpclient

The AsyncHttpClient version is 1.4.7.
The server recieves the request, but could not find the file param

Answer (score 1):

Working example

```
 HttpClient httpclient;
 HttpPost httppost;


 httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 httppost = new HttpPost(URLRepo.URL_IMAGESAVE);


List<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", ""+deichapp.getInt("userid", 0)));
//.. add parameters
File file = new File(new URI(obj.getString("fileUri")));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("filename", file.getName()));

httpclient.getParams().setParameter("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
httpclient.getParams().setParameter("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;");

MultipartEntityBuilder entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
                    for (BasicNameValuePair nameValuePair : nameValuePairs) {
            entity.addTextBody(nameValuePair.getName(), nameValuePair.getValue());
                    }

entity.addPart("file", new FileBody(new File(new URI(obj.getString("fileUri")))));

httppost.setEntity(entity.build());

// Send and store the Image
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    String json;
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
json = reader.readLine();
```

This uses the native android api and no external librarys like async http client. Make sure you execute this code on a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("notes", "Test api support"); 
    client.post(restApiUrl, params, responseHandler);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That example throws EOFException on my server.