# How to send parameters as Form parametrers instead of URL parameters with AsyncHttpClient in Android?

Tags: android, android-async-http, loopj

Currently I am creating parameters with:

```
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("Param1","Value1");
```

And then posting like this:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.post(restApiUrl, params, responseHandler);
```

However it makes it a URL parameter.

How to add it to body of the POST request as a Form parameter?

Comment: Please provide more code. How you pass the params to request?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android AsyncHttpClient: how to POST multipart form data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33649852/android-asynchttpclient-how-to-post-multipart-form-data)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html). Volley is an HTTP library that makes networking for Android apps easier and most importantly, faster. Volley is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/google/volley).

**Volley with GET:**

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext);
String url = "http://www.someurl.com?param1=value1&param2=value2"; // your url
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
           // here you will get the response from the url
           Log.d(TAG, response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // in case there is error in request, it'll be thrown here
            Log.e(TAG, error.toString);
        }
    });

    queue.add(stringRequest);
```

**Volley with POST:**

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext);
String url = "http://www.someurl.com"; // your url
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
           // here you will get the response from the url
           Log.d(TAG, response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // in case there is error in request, it'll be thrown here
            Log.e(TAG, error.toString);
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            // here you add params
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("param1", "value1");
            params.put("param2", "value2");
            return params;
        }
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            return super.getHeaders();
        }

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return super.getBodyContentType();
        }
    };
    queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simplest Way - Use URL Encoder Class**

*Sample AsyncTask Class*

that receives url,parameters in Arguments... You can pass any number of parameters in URL Encoder !

```
public class LongOperation  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
 
 
    Context context;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
 
    public LongOperation(Context context)
    {
        this.context=context;
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(context);
    }
 
 
    protected void onPreExecute() {
 
        progressDialog.setTitle("test");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading . . . .");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
        Toast.makeText(context,"loading . . .",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
 
    // Call after onPreExecute method
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
 
        try {
            URL url=new URL(urls[0]);
            URLConnection con=url.openConnection();
            con.setDoOutput(true);
 
            con.setDoInput(true);
 
            // request
            OutputStreamWriter io=new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
            // parameters
            io.write(URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(urls[1], "UTF-8"));
            io.flush();
 
            // response
            BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
 
            String line,received="";
 
            while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
            {
                received+=line;
            }
            return received;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return e.getMessage().toString();
        }
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String un) { 
       if(processDialog.isShowing())
            processDialog.dimiss();

    }
}
```